# Deserialize derived types in WCF service as base types but retain type information

Tags: wcf, serialization, types, datacontractserializer

I want my service to be able to accept and return types derived from `BaseType` without actually knowing what those types will be.  I have almost got a solution using a custom `DataContractResolver` based on the [SharedTypeResolver from this excellent blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/youssefm/archive/2009/06/05/introducing-a-new-datacontractserializer-feature-the-datacontractresolver.aspx).

The missing piece of the puzzle is that the types my service will handle might not be shared and known to the service but I still want to accept them and be aware of what the type should have been.  I have come up with the following example of a service that acts as a stack.  You can push and pop any type derived from `BaseType` provided you use the `SharedTypeResolver` and the types are shared between client and server.

```
[DataContract]
public class BaseType
{
    [DataMember]
    public string SomeText { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.GetType().Name + ": " + this.SomeText;
    }
}

[DataContract]
public class DerivedType : BaseType
{
    [DataMember]
    public int SomeNumber { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return base.ToString() + ", " + this.SomeNumber;
    }
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface ITypeStack
{
    [OperationContract]
    void Push(BaseType item);

    [OperationContract]
    BaseType Pop();
}

[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class TypeStackService : ITypeStack
{
    private Stack<BaseType> stack = new Stack<BaseType>();

    public void Push(BaseType item)
    {
        this.stack.Push(item);
    }

    public BaseType Pop()
    {
        return this.stack.Pop();
    }
}
```

This is obviously greatly a simplified example of the problem I'm having.  A client can quite merrily push and pop `BaseType` or `DerivedType` because both client and server know about them, but if the client pushes `UnsharedType` which the service does not know I get an error as you would expect.

> The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the
>   message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter
>   http://tempuri.org/:item. The InnerException message was 'Error in
>   line 1 position 316. Element 'http://tempuri.org/:item' contains data
>   from a type that maps to the name 'TestWcfClient, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null:TestWcfClient.UnsharedType'. The
>   deserializer has no knowledge of any type that maps to this name.
>   Consider changing the implementation of the ResolveName method on your
>   DataContractResolver to return a non-null value for name
>   'TestWcfClient.UnsharedType' and namespace 'TestWcfClient,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.'.  Please see
>   InnerException for more details.

My current thinking is to add `IExtensibleDataObject` to `BaseType` to hold the values from an unshared type and make an unshared type look like `BaseType` to the service on deserialization when an item is pushed; the opposite would need to happen when an item is popped.  I'm just not sure how to go about it.  My thoughts so far on possible approaches:

- Further customisation to `DataContractResolver` which might involve a `TypeDelegator`
- Using `IDataContractSurrogate` in place of an unshared type
- Somehow retain the serialized XML the service received when an item is pushed, then use this in the reply when an item is popped
- Using a message inspector to manipulate the messages

I've no idea if any of these will work, what would be involved or what is the best solution.  Do you?

Comment: Will you be changing objects on a service, or you just need to store them and send back to clients?

Comment: Just storing and sending them back.  I need to know about the base type as that has some properties the service uses to influence the storage, but it's read-only as far as the service is concerned.

Answer (score 3):

I have made some headway with this using a message inspector and a placeholder type that implements `IExtensibleDataObject`.  The inspector maniuplates the incoming message and changes the type hint to that of the placeholder and adds the original type as a property.  When the type is then sent out in a reply the opposite happens, thereby making the placeholder looks like the original type.

My grievance with this solution is that it is bound to the service because I have had to include the service's XML namespace and explicitly name the methods and parameters to be maniuplated.  Other than that is seems to work fairly well, though I have only tested it on fairly simple types derived from `BaseType`.

Can anyone improve on this?  There's a bounty in it for you.

```
public class PlaceholderType : BaseType, IExtensibleDataObject
{
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public string OriginalTypeName { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public string OriginalNamespace { get; set; }

    ExtensionDataObject IExtensibleDataObject.ExtensionData { get; set; }
}

public class FunkadelicInspector : IDispatchMessageInspector, IContractBehavior
{
    const string PlaceholderNamespace = "http://my.placeholder.namespace";
    const string ServiceNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/";

    public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = ReadMessage(request);

        XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
        // Dislike: having to know the service namespace, method and parameters
        nsmgr.AddNamespace("s", ServiceNamespace);
        XmlNode itemElement = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//s:Push/s:item", nsmgr);

        if (itemElement != null)
        {
            XmlAttribute typeAttribute = itemElement.Attributes["type", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"];
            if (typeAttribute != null)
            {
                // Record original type
                string[] parts = typeAttribute.Value.Split(':');
                string originalTypeName = parts[1];
                // Replace with placeholder type
                typeAttribute.Value = parts[0] + ":" + typeof(PlaceholderType).FullName;

                // Record original assembly
                XmlAttribute nsAtt = itemElement.Attributes["xmlns:" + parts[0]];
                string originalAssembly = nsAtt.Value;
                // Replace with placeholder type's assembly
                nsAtt.Value = typeof(PlaceholderType).Assembly.FullName;

                // Add placeholders
                itemElement.AppendChild(xmlDoc.CreateElement("OriginalType", PlaceholderNamespace)).InnerText = originalTypeName;
                itemElement.AppendChild(xmlDoc.CreateElement("OriginalAssembly", PlaceholderNamespace)).InnerText = originalAssembly;
            }
        }

        //Now recreate the message
        request = WriteMessage(request, xmlDoc);
        return null;
    }

    public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = ReadMessage(reply);

        XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);
        nsmgr.AddNamespace("s", ServiceNamespace);
        nsmgr.AddNamespace("plc", PlaceholderNamespace);
        // Dislike: having to know the service namespace, method and parameters
        XmlNode resultElement = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("//s:PopResponse/s:PopResult", nsmgr);

        if (resultElement != null)
        {
            XmlElement originalType = resultElement.SelectSingleNode("plc:OriginalType", nsmgr) as XmlElement;
            XmlElement originalAssembly = resultElement.SelectSingleNode("plc:OriginalAssembly", nsmgr) as XmlElement;
            if (originalType != null && originalAssembly != null)
            {
                // Replace original type
                XmlAttribute type = resultElement.Attributes["type", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"];
                string[] parts = type.Value.Split(':'); // 0 is an alias for the assembly, 1 is the type
                type.Value = parts[0] + ":" + originalType.InnerText;

                // Replace original assembly
                XmlAttribute ass = resultElement.Attributes["xmlns:" + parts[0]];
                ass.Value = originalAssembly.InnerText;

                // Remove placeholders
                resultElement.RemoveChild(originalType);
                resultElement.RemoveChild(originalAssembly);
            }
        }

        //Now recreate the message
        reply = WriteMessage(reply, xmlDoc);
    }

    private static Message WriteMessage(Message original, XmlDocument xmlDoc)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        xmlDoc.Save(ms);
        ms.Position = 0;
        XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(ms);
        Message newMessage = Message.CreateMessage(reader, int.MaxValue, original.Version);
        newMessage.Properties.CopyProperties(original.Properties);
        return newMessage;
    }

    private static XmlDocument ReadMessage(Message message)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(ms))
        {
            message.WriteMessage(writer); // the message was consumed here
            writer.Flush();
        }
        ms.Position = 0;
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load(ms);
        return xmlDoc;
    }

    void IContractBehavior.AddBindingParameters(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
    {
    }

    void IContractBehavior.ApplyClientBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
    {
    }

    void IContractBehavior.ApplyDispatchBehavior(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint, DispatchRuntime dispatchRuntime)
    {
        dispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(this);
    }

    void IContractBehavior.Validate(ContractDescription contractDescription, ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {
    }
}
```